# How to switch between light and dark modes via command line in win 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, shell

Is there a command line to set the color personalization Dark or Light in the Colors settings?

Answer (score 1):

To set win 10 light mode:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name SystemUsesLightTheme -Value 1 -Type Dword -Force; New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme -Value 1 -Type Dword -Force
```

to set the dark

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name SystemUsesLightTheme -Value 0 -Type Dword -Force; New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme -Value 0 -Type Dword -Force
```

credits to [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-switch-between-light-and-dark-colors-schedule-automatically-windows-10) blog post that aims to do it automatically.