# Changing the windows theme using command prompt

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-11, themes

i want to ask how to change the windows theme using command prompt? this is basically to fix a problem. someone likes light theme  i like dark theme. to fix this hassle since time to use pc is random, i wanna create 2 scripts, 1 to change to dark theme and another to light theme. i have tried searching this issue but it instead shows how to change the theme of cmd itself.

Comment: What have you tried? [Edit] your question to include any relevant information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch between light and dark modes via command line in win 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1544089/how-to-switch-between-light-and-dark-modes-via-command-line-in-win-10) (i know its win10 but not much has changed)

Comment: or for example https://winaero.com/how-to-change-the-theme-in-windows-11/#Change_Theme_in_Windows_11_from_Command_Prompt